# Evaluate a string as a verb in J

Tags: string, function, eval, j

## TL;DR

Given a string containing a (valid) verb, how do I obtain that verb without committing it to any variables? For example, say `eval` is that function; it should work like this:

```
   eval '+ @ >: @ %'
+@>:@%
   eval '+'
+
```

I only need it to be able to execute verbs and return them, but it would be cool to have arbitrary code be eval'd. (I do know about `".`, BTW.)

---

As a fun little experiment, I thought "hey, maybe I can make a verb that will transform a string of verbs into a train of verbs!" I know that I can use `;:` to "word-ify" the string into J-verbs, like so:

```
   ]str =: '+ >: %'
+ >: %
   ;: str
┌─┬──┬─┐
│+│>:│%│
└─┴──┴─┘
```

So far, so good. Now, I just will primatively "join" them with `'@'` by using `,.` ("ravel items"):

```
   '@' ,.~ > ;: str
+ @
>:@
% @
```

Flattening this yields:

```
+ @>:@% @
```

And finally, chopping off the trailing `@` with `}:` yields `+ @>:@%`, an uglier version of what I want, `+ @ >: @ %`.

Now, this is all good and well, except for one thing: it's a string. Almost there! But not quite. I thought to myself, "Oh! `".` would be perfect for this, it's basically eval." To my dismay, the docs read thus (emph mine):

> `".y` executes the sentence `y`. If the execution results in a noun, the result of `".y` is that noun; **if the execution result is a verb**, adverb, or conjunction, or if there is no execution result, **the result of `".y` is an empty vector.**

Well, darnit. That won't work. I can certainly hack it together by defining a verb from within the string:

```
]verb =: , }: , '@' ,.~ > ;: str
+ @>:@% 
   'ret =: ' , verb
ret =: + @>:@% 
   ". 'ret =: ' , verb
   ret
+@>:@%
```

And this is all well and good, but rather clumsy, especially for J. The blow can be softened slightly with this `is` verb:

```
   is =: ".@(,&'=:'@,@[,}:@,@('@',.~>@;:)@])
   'G' is '+>:%'
   G
+@>:@%
   G 5
1.2
```

But only works if you're willing to commit the function to a variable.

So, my question stands: how do I convert a generic string holding a verb into a usable verb?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Evoke gerund** (`` `: ``) is what you want. Please refer to [this short documentation](http://www.jsoftware.com/docs/help804/dictionary/d612.htm) for good examples. And in your case:

```
   str=: '+ @ >: @ %'
   (;: str) `:6
+@>:@%
```

You may want to review [**Tie**](http://www.jsoftware.com/docs/help804/dictionary/d610.htm) (`` ` ``) to understand this. `;:` returns gerunds in our case (atomic representations), and `` m `: 6 `` converts gerund `m` to verb train.

Alternatively

```
   str =: '+ >: %'
   g =: verb def (str,' y')
   g 5
1.2
```

You can also try `monad` or `dyad` if you wish, e.g.

```
    2 (dyad def 'x * + % y') 5
0.4
```

Or to make a train, wrap `str` in parenthesis:

```
   2 (dyad def 'x (* + %) y') 5
10.4
```